# [NeedsToUpgradeAsync]..Engine PostgreSQL version 110016 is not supported. Please upgrade your server to the last version

Tags: c#, synchronization

I'm trying to syncronize a PostgreSQL database (server) with a SQLite database (client) using Dotmim.Sync, but I'm getting this error:

### [NeedsToUpgradeAsync]..Engine PostgreSQL version 110016 is not supported. Please upgrade your server to the last version.

└  ─ Engine PostgreSQL version 110016 is not supported. Please upgrade your server to the last version.

Is there a way to make the sync work for the current PostgreSQL version?

Upgrading the PostgreSQL version is out of the question, I just want to know if there's any possibility to make the sync work with the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, don't think it's possible right now according to this discussion from their GitHub: https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync/discussions/951. They require **Postgres 15+**